# Users with contribute permission can call REST API to Break Role Inheritance , but can not make a REST API call to get all role assignments

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate, flow

I have a power automate flow which runs under a user who have Contribute permission on a list item, the flow consists of 2 actions:-

[image]

First action is to break role inheritance, while the second flow to get all the role assignments. now the user (who have contribute permission) can perform the first action, but will get unauthorized access on the second action. So is this a bug inside SharePoint rest API?

Comment: I just tried the same scenario, seems like a bug in SharePoint REST API. I have added my findings below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the same scenario to get the role assignments of list items using power automate flow:

[image]

Here are my findings:

| User Permissions | Flow works/Error |
| --- | --- |
| Contribute | Error |
| Edit | Error |
| Design | Error |
| Full Control | Flow works |

**Similar thread**: [Unexpected 403 in SharePoint REST API list items roleassignments call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66324448/unexpected-403-in-sharepoint-rest-api-list-items-roleassignments-call) - Answer on this thread states: *Requires Full Control rights in order to access RoleAssignments*